# Selenium Loop Through Links

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In selenium, in python,
I have to loop through Jira1, jira2, jira3 links

for i in range(1,4):
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Jira']+/str(i)").click()

It is giving me an error
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='Jira+str(i)']"}
(Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)

How do I resolve that

Comment: Use driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Jira"+i+"']").click() instead.

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable in building the XPath you should correctly insert that variable like @Martheen is commenting.

So in stead of:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Jira']+/str(i)").click()
```

Use this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Jira" + i +"']").click()
```

this will build i.e. the XPath: `//a[text()='Jira1']`

To have better controle over your loop and to know what is going on your loop, you could first build the XPath string and then use it, i.e. like this:

```
for i in range(1,4):
   XPathInLoop = "//a[text()='Jira" + i + "']"
   print(XPathInLoop)
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH,XPathInLoop).click()
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?